# How do I find out the principal minors of a $4\times 4$ matrix?

Tags: matrices

How many principal minors can a $4\times 4$ matrix have?

Is there any general method using which I can found out the principal minors of any $n\times n$ matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

- $4 =\binom{4}{1}$ principal minor of order $1$
- $6 =\binom{4}{2}$ principal minor of order $2$
- $4 =\binom{4}{3}$ principal minor of order $3$

Comment: Thank you for answering. But, how do I find out these principal minors. For a 3X3 matrix, I find them by removing the last columns and rows, and then the first two columns and rows and finally the first two columns and rows. How does it work for a 4 X 4 matrix?

Comment: @WorldGov for a 4-by-4 matrix for the minor of order 3 we need to eliminate the i^th row and the i^th column for i=1,2,3,4 thus we find 4 minors of order 3. For the minors of order 2 we need to eliminate 2 rows and 2 corresponding columns with $(i,j)=(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)$ thus we find 6 minors of order 2 and so on.

Comment: That helped, thank you!

Comment: @WorldGov I'm happy for that! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

The principal minors of a square matrix are just the [deterimants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of the corresponding submatrices. Wikipedia describes it very well, see [Minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)).